# Google Script does not return String

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Spreadsheet function that takes two arguments and return into a SEO-friendly version for my online shop.

However the Google script part doesn't seems to be working quite the way I can understand.

```js
function convunit(amt, unit) {
  var unit = String(unit);

  switch (unit) {
    case 'ml':
      if (value >= 1000) {
        return roundoff(value * 0.035) + "fl.oz/" + value / 1000 + "L";
      } else {
        return roundoff(value * 0.035) + "fl.oz/" + value + "ml";
      }
    case 'g':
      if (value >= 1000) {
        var standard = value / 1000 + "kg";
      } else {
        var standard = value + "g";
      }
      var imperial = value * 0.04;
      if (imperial >= 16) {
        imperial = imperial / 16 + "lbs";
      } else {
        imperial = imperial + "oz";
      }




      return imperial + "/" + standard;
  }



}
```

The result will always be an empty cell feeding back into GoogleSheet.

However, I was able to isolate the problem to the point where I can't really understand what's going on.

```js
function convunitif(amt, ut) {

  return ut;

}
```

The end result of this function should return whatever the user inputs as "ut", but it ends up with "#NAME?"

[Faulty function result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7XPr.png)

I even checked by using typeof to check what's in ut, and it did return "string". Please help.

[Google Sheet Sample with script included.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TI0jX4tyAFAgxoJgvXyxdfzX0l6O1NEKn9EIKgZpb2Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: create an example spreadsheet and then make it public so we can take a look at it. Also, what does it say if you hover the mouse pointer over the cell that shows `#NAME`?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TI0jX4tyAFAgxoJgvXyxdfzX0l6O1NEKn9EIKgZpb2Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, should've included a link to it.

It shows nothing when hovering the mouse pointer over the cell that shows #NAME?

Comment: shows convunitif(1200,ml)

Comment: `ml` is not a string. Try `"ml"`. Or put a cell reference in there instead.

Comment: It displays `#NAME?` because `ml` is an unknown name.

Comment: also not so clear why if the parameter is called amt the function keeps working with value.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Sorry, I should've replaced it with amt because "amt" stands for amount, and it's the volumn/weight that users feeds into the formular.

Comment: Also, did you define a "roundoff" function? I am pretty sure the built in one is "round"?

Comment: @SpiderPig Ah snap, that worked, don't know why I tried that this morning but the function didn't work as intended. The formula works properly now. I wanted that to be a switch/case function, but by using "ml" didn't work, so I had to switch back to if/else.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Yes I did

function roundoff(value){
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+2)+'e-'+2);
}

Because the round function is giving me really weird results.

Comment: Add a return "other"; at the end, for debug purposes, to catch when switch doesn't match "g" nor "ml".

Comment: @AlejandroSilvestri that's actually a good idea, thanks!!